# Any side effect of not using USES_CONVERSION

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Recently I made a utilities function like:

```
// T2CA
#include "ATLCONV.H"

std::string Utils::CString2String(const CString& cString) 
{
#if _MSC_VER > 1200
    // Convert a TCHAR string to a LPCSTR
    // construct a std::string using the LPCSTR input
    CT2CA tmp(cString);
    std::string strStd (tmp);
#else
    // Deprecated in VC2008.
    // construct a std::string using the LPCSTR input

    std::string strStd (T2CA (cString));
#endif

    return strStd;
}
```

I did several simple tests and it seems to work fine. However, when I search the web I can see that most usages of T2CA in VC6 have a preceding call of

```
USES_CONVERSION;
```

Is there anything that I had missed? Should I invoke my function by :

```
#else
    // Deprecated in VC2008.
    // construct a std::string using the LPCSTR input
    USES_CONVERSION;
    std::string strStd (T2CA (cString));
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ATL 7.0 `USES_CONVERSION` is not required anymore.  Before that you needed to specify the `USES_CONVERSION` macro or else you'd get compile errors.

Comment: But how come I didn't get any compilation error when I use T2CA? Take note T2CA is called with VC6 code block (#if _MSC_VER <= 1200)

Comment: @Yan: I'm not sure but I remember before doing development and if I didn't put it I'd get compiling errors. And I know it's not required anymore.  I think it's safe to say that you can safely use code without it if it compiles fine.

Comment: Oh, if I switch to unicode in VC6, I will get compilation error. Look like USES_CONVERSION is a must.