# What is the best alternative to using ENSURE to avoid code analysis warnings?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis

Example:

```
ENSURE(strTitle.LoadString(AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE));
ENSURE(strMainInstruction.LoadString(IDS_STR_SUBMIT_STATS_MAIN_TEXT));
ENSURE(strContent.LoadString(IDS_STR_SUBMIT_STATS_CONTENT_TEXT));
ENSURE(strAdditional.LoadString(IDS_STR_SUBMIT_STATS_ADDITIONAL_TEXT));
ENSURE(strFooter.LoadString(IDS_STR_TASK_DIALOG_FOOTER));
ENSURE(strVerification.LoadString(IDS_STR_SUBMIT_STATS_VERIFICATION_TEXT));
ENSURE(strExpand.LoadString(IDS_STR_FIND_OUT_MORE));
ENSURE(strCollapse.LoadString(IDS_STR_COLLAPSE));
```

Definition:

```
#define ENSURE(cond) ENSURE_THROW(cond, ::AfxThrowInvalidArgException() )
```

It is a Microsoft macro, although I can't see it documented. I started using it when I noticed it being used in Microsoft SDK code. Annoyingly it triggers  code analysis:

> Warning C26496: The variable '__afx_condVal' does not change after construction, mark it as const (con.4).

I did raise it with [Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Using-ENSURE-flags-code-analysis-warning/1559118). The underlying macro `ENSURE_THROW`:

```
#define ENSURE_THROW(cond, exception)   \
    do { int __afx_condVal=!!(cond); ASSERT(__afx_condVal); if (!(__afx_condVal)){exception;} } __pragma(warning(suppress:4127)) while (false)
```

... it only needs the word `const` to resolve it.

---

Is there an alternative call I can make because I understand that `ASSERT` only works in `DEBUG` build.

Comment: Ensure is pretty well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/diagnostic-services?view=msvc-160#ensure)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the link. I tried `ENSURE` and nothign was coming up ...

Comment: First hit on google with _mfc ensure macro_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redefine `ENSURE_THROW` and put this into your `stdafx.h`:

```
#undef ENSURE_THROW
#define ENSURE_THROW(cond, exception)   \
    do { const int __afx_condVal=!!(cond); ASSERT(__afx_condVal); \
    if (!(__afx_condVal)){exception;} } while (false)
```

It's identical to the original MS definiton in `afx.h`, but with the `const` added.

This could break in future versions of MFC, although it is unlikely that MS will ever change this.

A cleaner way would be excluding certain header files from the analysis, but this depends on your tool.

Be aware that `ENSURE` and `ASSERT` are very different things:

- `ASSERT(x)` : in debug builds it will stop the program execution with a message if `x` is false, in release builds it's a NOP, `x` won't even be evaluated
- `ENSURE(x)` : `x` will be evaluated and if it's false an exception will be thrown. In debug builds a diagnostic dialog is shown before the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks. I have the Exclude Directories setup. So none of the ENSURE calls flag for the MFC SDK code itself. It is in my own files and can’t be excluded. Thanks again.

Comment: This fits nicely into [the architecture of a C compiler](https://twitter.com/Cor3ntin/status/1442249542313861123).

Comment: Honestly, this is worse than any code analysis warning. It's a UB foot gun so subtle, that neither compiler nor linker have any chance of taking note. They will just dutifully output code whose behavior is quite potentially undefined. Also, excluding files from code analysis doesn't work with preprocessor macros. The macros get replaced before the analyzer is involved. Once it gets to see the code, it no longer knows that part of it came from a macro defined in a file that was supposed to be ignored.

Comment: @IInspectable could you please tell us more why UB is involved here? You're right about the excluding though.

Comment: You are compiling part of your code where a preprocessor macro expands to one thing, and the other part of your code where it expands to something else. And now those two parts are talking to each other. If I'd put enough thought into it, I'd be able to fabricate a situation where this hurts. Though, why not replace `ENSURE`, and give it a new name? Better yet, since we have [`source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location), there's no reason to use a macro at all. Just make it a function template.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the explanation. Making another `MY_ENSURE` instead of redefining the MFC one is probably better. OTOH your template solution is probably even better, you should post an answer using this solution.

Comment: @IInspectable Please post it for me. I can isolate my inmstances of ENSURE and make teh changes. Mind you, there are other macros that fail too, like `USES_CONVERSION`. But stick to one macro here.

Comment: @and I'll post an answer when I find time, not sure when that will be though. As for `USES_CONVERSION`, that's no longer needed, and hasn't been for more than a decade. As far as I know, you can just remove it, and still use the string conversion macros. Sadly, I couldn't find any official documentation, that explains what `USES_CONVERSION` was needed for, nor which version of MFC/ATL removed that requirement.

Comment: @IInspectable See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994602/2287576